# Create new Document in Document library with additional Text Fields in Silverlight (Client Object Model)

Tags: 2010, document-library, client-object-model, silverlight

I have created a Silverlight Application that runs in a SharePoint 2010 web part.

One requirement I have is to give the user a prompt to upload a file, and then send it into a specific Document Library with the additional Fields 'First' and 'Last' (Name corresponding to whom the document is from).

I am able to create the document and upload it to SharePoint. At this point however I hit an impasse. The normal means (as far as I'm aware) to add a Document to a Document Library is something similar to the following...

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(ApplicationContext.Current.Url);
context.Load(context.Web);
List docList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyDocLib");
context.Load(docList);

docList.RootFolder.Files.Add(myFile); // Assuming of course the file is retrieved already
context.ExecuteQuery(); // Or ExecuteQueryAsync for more functionality
```

Unfortunately this leaves no room to add in the extra fields i need.

Furthermore the only thing received if i were to use something like

```
File file = docList.RootFolder.Files.Add(myFile);
```

does not seem to have an association with the library to build off of and then run another ExecuteQuery()

I would imagine there would be a way of treating the Document Library as a List (I'm fairly sure from a technical perspective they amount to the same thing) for its item creation, however I do not know how to create it properly.

If someone could give me advice on how to proceed, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there, using your `Files.Add` method as shown you can then set properties like this:

```
File file = docList.RootFolder.Files.Add(myFile);
ListItem item = file.ListItemAllFields;
item["Title"] = "Super Awesome File!";
item.Update();
```

**References:**

- [File.ListItemAllFields Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.listitemallfields.aspx)
- [ListItem Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem_members.aspx)

Comment: Great! Thanks, I'll try it right now and then set it as an answer!